# Java socket array (custom class) returns null pointer exception

Tags: java, arrays, sockets

I created a custom class for sockets:

```
class clientSocket{

    Socket clientSocket = null;

    public clientSocket() {

    }

    void accept(ServerSocket welcomeSocket) throws IOException{
        clientSocket = welcomeSocket.accept();
    }
}
```

When I try to use it in my server class like below, it throws a null pointer exception:

```
ServerSocket sSocket = new ServerSocket(1234);
clientSocket[] client = new clientSocket[3];
client[0].accept(sSocket); //this throws a null pointer exception.
```

Any idea why the 3rd line throws that null pointer?

Comment: When you initialize a new array you do not initialize its content. So you need to first use `client[0] = new ClientSocket()`. Also please note that classes are capitalized by convention.

Comment: @Ben Thanks, that was the solution.